# UnicodeDecodeError while streaming video

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, socket.io

I am writing a python script to stream video data from an ip camera to a web application via socketio. The problem is here:

```
sio.emit('my response', {'data': camera_buffer},
                 namespace='/test')
```

Here is the raised UnicodeDecodeError, as the camera_buffer represents binary data in ffmpeg format. My question is, how can I tell Python that this is binary data and not a string? Or just how to prevent from decoding it?

The only thing that worked so far has been using binascii.hexlify(camera_buffer), but I'd like to avoid this, as it causes me an unnecessary overhead. 
I also tried to  send data as a bytearray.
My OS is Ubuntu 15.10.

EDIT: is there any way to read data from pipe not as string, but in binary form? I guess that this can help. I tried `io=open('name_of_pipe','rb')`, but reading from this still returns 'str'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Can you try:

```
name_of_pipe_binary =  os.fdopen('name_of_pipe', 'rb', 0)
```

and then use "name_of_pipe_binary" instead of "name_of_pipe" ?

---

For more info please take a look at: http://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#socketio.Server.emit

```
emit(event, data=None, room=None, skip_sid=None, namespace=None, callback=None)
```

data – The data to send to the client or clients. Data can be of type **str, bytes, list or dict**

Comment: This doesn't work, because 'data' is named argument of `emit` function. And I think that my problem appears a bit earlier, when I read data from pipe - I just need Python to treat it as binary, not string, if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've suggest another idea - using os.fdopen which will set the open to be 'rb'

Comment: Solved - I use Python 3 instead of Python 2 and pure websockets instead of socketio.